# Unable to connect to Wildfly server in intellij

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-15

I am using Wildfly server for my application. I am running this server through intellij plugin. Whenever I run this application I am getting an error message

```
"Error running 'JBoss 9.0.1.Final': Unable to connect to the localhost:8080"
```

Here is my configuration in intellij.

[image]

Comment: What is the Wildfly log saying? Is port 8080 free?

Comment: @JoachimRohde Yes , The port is free. There is nothing in the log.When i run application simply above mentioned message occurs.

Comment: In your standalone.xml you have an `interfaces` tag, please post what is inside that tag. Whats version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your standalone.xml, add this to it and try again.

Also, check your Java version. Wildfly 9 uses Java 7/8, maybe you need to downgrade Java version or update Wildfly to 14 or 15.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>

    <!-- add the code below -->
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="any">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

You can check [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as) the best versions of each, so you can start your server without problems. Regards.